# Using the template in 404, 403, 500, etc error pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm just thinking if I can made this work in a cool, DRY way.. but i'm pretty new to rails and have no idea of how can I do that..

Any help?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out:

```
rescue_from Foo::BarException do |exception|
    render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/403", formats: [:html], status: 403, layout: true
end
```

Then do the 403.html like a boss, and it should work.

But, I still not knowing how to made the automatic 404 use the template too... it always shows the exception, even if I add the rescue in my application controller.